# Autogenerated files not present in flutter package dependency imported via git URL

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I've developed a private Flutter package that uses [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable). When developing the package I need to run `dart run build_runner build` to perform code autogeneration (and to generate Mockito mock files). Note that I gitignore the autogenerated files. I am testing out including that package via its git URL in a separate app. Adding the private package to the app appears successful (so this is not an ssh issue). However when I build the app, build errors ensue pertaining to the missing autogenerated files.

How do I get the package's autogenerated and gitignored files to be built when the package is added? I've played around with adding a `build.yaml` file to the package without success.